# Structuring mogodb schema

Tags: mongodb, schema, database-schema

I'm playing around with MongoDB and was wondering what best practices are for how a SQL-ish schema may correspond to MongoDB. Here are the tables/data I have so far:

- `user`

  - id
  - email
  - name
- `answer`

  - user_id (FK user.id)
  - tag
  - upvotes
- `repo`

  - id
  - owner
  - name
  - description
  - stars
- `repo_tag`

  - repo_id (FK to repo.id)
  - tag
  - is_language
  - percentage
- `repo_contrib`

  - repo_id (FK to repo.id)
  - user_id (FK to user.id)
  - lines_of_code

The structure goes something like this:

- user

  - answer (left outer)
  - repo_contrib (left outer)

    - repo

      - repo_tag

Note: All users will have at least one answer or one repo, but does not necessarily have to have both.

How might I put this into a mongo schema? Would this be one 'collection' ? Or would this be two collections: one for user, and one for repo; or more?

My queries will be something like: "Grab all users with an Answer with tay [Python] with more than 2 upvotes or a repo with the [Python] tag with more than two stars.

Comment: To model with MongoDB's flexible schema, one of the details required is the amount/size of the data. The important factors (among others) that affect a model are the size and the usage (the important queries, includes all CRUD operations).

Answer (score 4):

Let me divide this to couple of steps:

**STEP 1 - MONGODB and MONGOOSE**

MongoDB is a document based database. Each record in a collection is a document, and every document should be self-contained (it should contain all information that you need inside it).

Since MongoDB is a no-relation database, you can not create relations between collections, but you can store a reference of one collection document as a property of another collection document. To help you manage all of this, there is a great package called `Mongoose`, which will allow you to create a Model for each Collection. After you define
Models, `Mongoose` will allow you to easily make queries to database.

**STEP 2 - DEFINING MODELS**

As we said, documents should be self-contained, so they should have all information that you need inside them. We can have 2 approaches based on your example:

APPROACH 1:

Create one collection for each table that you have in your relational database. This is the best practice when you have documents with a lot of data, because it is scalable.

APPROACH 2:

Create 3 Collections - USERS, ANSWERS and REPOS. Because `repo_contrib` does not have a lot of data, you can store all user's contributions in a USERS document. That way, when you fetch a User document, you will have everything that you need in one place. The same goes for `repo_tag` - we can store all repo's tags in a REPOS document.

APPROACH 3:

Create 2 Collections - USERS and REPOS. The same as APPROACH 2, but you can also add all user's `answers` to the USERS document.

RECOMMENDATION:

I would go with APPROACH 2 in this case, since `repo_contrib` and `repo_tag` does not store big data and can easily be stored in USERS and REPOS documents with no problem. Also, if we go with this approach, it will make querying database a lot easier. The reason why I didn't choose option 3 is because theoretically user can have thousands or tens of thousands of answers, and it would not scale well.

**STEP 3 - IMPLEMENTATION**

NOTE: MongoDB will automatically assign `_id` to each document, so you don't have to define `id` property when implementing Models.

Tables from your relational database example can be mapped to collections like this (This implementation is for APPROACH 2):

USERS Collection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
    contributions: [{
      repo_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'REPOS' },
      lines_of_code: { type: Numeric, ref: 'REPOS' }
    }]
});
const Users = mongoose.model('USERS', schema);
module.exports = Users;
```

ANSWERS Collection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    user_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'USERS', required: true },
    tag: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
    upvotes:{ type: Number, default: 0, unique: false }
});
const Answers = mongoose.model('ANSWERS', schema);
module.exports = Answers;
```

REPOS Collection:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    owner: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'USERS', required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
    description: { type: String, required: false, unique: false },
    stars:{ type: Number, default: 0, unique: false },
    tags: [{
      name:  { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
      is_language: {type: Boolean, required: true, unique: false},
      percentage:{ type: Number, default: 0, unique: false }
    }]
});
const Repos = mongoose.model('REPOS', schema);
module.exports = Repos ;
```

**STEP 4 - POPULATION AND DATABASE QUERIES**

One of the best features of the `Mongoose` is called `population`. If you store a reference of one collection document as a property of another collection document, when performing querying of the database, `Mongoose` will  replace references with the actual documents.

Example 1:

Let us first take as an example the first query that you suggested: `Find all users with an Answer with tag [Python] with more than 2 upvotes`. Since we stored `user_id` in ANSWERS Collection as a reference to the document from the USERS collection, that means that we can just query the ANSWERS Collection, and when returning the final result `Mongoose` will go to USERS collection and replace the references with the actual User documents. The database query that will perform this looks like this:

```
const ANSWERS = require('../models/answers');

ANSWERS.find({
  "tag": "Python",
  "upvotes": {
    "$gt": 2
  }
}).populate('user_id');
```

Example 2:

Second query that you have suggested is: `Find all repos with the [Python] tag with more than two stars`. Since we are storing all repo's tags in one array, we just need to check if that array contains an item with the `name` field that is equal to `Python`, and that the repo's `stars` fields is greater than 2. The database query that will perform this looks like this:

```
const REPOS = require('../models/repos');

REPOS.find({
  "tags.name": "Python",
  "stars": {
    "$gt": 2
  }
})
```

Here is also the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rgBtVVDgPzG

Answer (score 2):

Designing a database model is very complex most of the time and I guess you are looking for best practices *from a reputable source*. I think this is the missing point in the other answers, even if @NenadMilosavljevic got close to it.

#### Brief introduction on NoSQL modeling

You are probably used to model SQL databases, for NoSQL modeling it is totally different. These are some of the differences:

| SQL Modeling | NoSQL modeling |
| --- | --- |
| This type of modeling is "data-oriented" in the sense that it is designed to be used and shared by many applications. Data is normalized, generally using normal forms, to avoid duplication and to make future changes easier and with lowest downtime possible. | NoSQL modeling is "application-oriented" because it should be built from the requirements of a single application, in order to reach the maximum level of optimization. |
| You start from requirements analysis, then the conceptual design, in the end the physical design. | If you want to optimize your application, you need to start from the app itself and from the operations needed: this is the so-called workload. After that there are conceptual and physical design of course. |

I want to focus on the workload a little more because it is very important. Since you come from a SQL-based application, you can describe the workload starting from various scenarios, production logs and statistics. For each query you need, these parameters are essential:

- Size of data requested
- Frequency of the query
- The complexity of the operations involved

---

Returning to the original question: *"My queries will be something like..."* is not enough for me to help you on building a NoSQL model. There are many solutions for your problem but, unless you provide a lot more info on the queries you need to do, they are all correct.

@NenadMilosavljevic gave you multiple approaches, but I can't say if the second one is the correct one for the reasons I have told you above. For example, he suggests to keep `user` and user contributions together so that you have to perform a single query to retrieve them, instead of doing `JOIN`s or something even more expensive.
This is certainly clever but suppose, and it is probably not your case, that you have to update the user contributions very often, then in this case keeping them in a separate collection might be better.

What I am saying is that too many assumptions are missing and the solution we give you could be good but not optimal.
Honestly, it is not clear to me if you need a trivial conversion from a SQL model to NoSQL model, or you are trying to apply the NoSQL principles. I have no idea about the size of your database, but if performances are not a problem, just go with the solution you find more appropriate. Doing a research on how to better model your data would be a waste of time.

Instead, if you really need to design a NoSQL database, not a SQL-like NoSQL database, then my advice is to follow [this course](https://university.mongodb.com/mercury/M320/2021_May_18/overview). Actually, you could finish it in less than 5 hours and many lessons are unnecessary in your situation, but it is worth taking a look at it. No one here talked about patterns and how to deal with one-to-zillion relationships for instance. It is very important to know their existence unless you like to redesign your database when it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion. My suggestion would be 3 collections. There are `user`, `repo` and `answer`. Below are the schemas for reference.

user collection

```
id: String
email: String
name: String
```

repo collection

```
id: String
owner: String
name: String
description: String
tag: [String] // Array of string
contributors: [Number] // Array of user id
```

I suggest having another collection named `answer`. This is because a user could provide a lot of answers. Thus, having it on another collection will be easier to query compare to having it inside subdocuments of `user` collection.

answer collection

```
answer_id
user_id
tag
upvotes
```

I hope it is helpful.

Comment: thanks, what's the advantage of having these three in separate collections? Also, the `user` is the primary object, and wouldn't it be quite difficult to join the user with a list field on the contributors? That is, to get all the repos for a given user?

Comment: The advantage really depends on how you would query the data. Right now, I only separate it based on some logical thinking. My assumption is


- List all the answers given by the users
- List all the repo
- List all the repo belongs a users and etc.


Get all repo for a given users is easy with MongoDB. You could use $in operators to find the user id whether exist in contributors. Thus, you could get all the repo for a given user.

Comment: I've added a bounty to the question. Want to elaborate? How would the join query look like then?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo Schema design 101: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1.

If in SQL you think about data in object oriented way - your models represent some business entities
and you build functions around them, in Mongo you should think functional way - what data you have as
input and what you need as output. In other words your schema should be based on queries you need
to run, not on data you have.

It is a bit more tricky as there is no best way - any schema will be better for some queries than for others.
You will need to choose which queries should be prioritized. To make it even more interesting, you will need
to anticipate which queries you may have in the future.

And of course it's all about data size. If it fits into single server you have luxury of aggregation lookups to "join" collections.
Otherwise sharding will significantly restrict your choices.

On the other hand embedding should be used with care - document size cannot exceed 16MB and modification
of embedded documents is not that straightforward.

The last but not least thing to consider are indexes. Your schema should allow efficient indexes for your queries. Here you will need to consider not only data size but also its quality - selectivity/cardinality

In the light of the foregoing the best schema to "grab all users with an Answer with tay [Python] with more than 2 upvotes or a repo with the [Python] tag with more than two stars" will be a 2 collections:

user:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "email": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "answers": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "bsonType": "object",
          "properties": {
            "tag": {
              "bsonType": "string"
            },
            "upvotes": {
              "bsonType": "int"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "tag",
            "upvotes"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "email",
    "name",
    "answers"
  ]
}
```

repo:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "owner": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "stars": {
      "bsonType": "int"
    },
    "tags": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "bsonType": "object",
          "properties": {
            "tag": {
              "bsonType": "string"
            },
            "is_language": {
              "bsonType": "bool"
            },
            "percentage": {
              "bsonType": "double"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "tag",
            "is_language",
            "percentage"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "contributors": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "bsonType": "object",
          "properties": {
            "user_id": {
              "bsonType": "objectid"
            },
            "lines_of_code": {
              "bsonType": "int"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "user_id",
            "lines_of_code"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "owner",
    "name"
    "description",
    "stars"
  ]
}
```

with the queries:

```
db.user.find({answers: {$elemMatch:{tag:"Python", upvotes:{$gt:2}}}})
db.repo.find({"tags.tag":"Python", stars:{$gt:2}})
```

In the comment you mentioned something like  "to get all the repos for a given user". Assuming it's about contributors, otherwise you don't need this array at all.
The query will be:

```
db.repo.find({"contributors.user_id": ObjectId("12313212313232")})
```